# Can Silverlight Run on linux

Tags: linux

I have just read an article on microsoft brining silverlight to linux OS. Does this mean that when I create my project on windows box will it be able to run on linux? Do I need to do anything else to the code to have it run on linux?

Comment: Should questions end in a question mark.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Moonlight is an open source
>   implementation of Silverlight
>   (http://silverlight.net), primarily
>   for Linux and other Unix/X11 based
>   operating systems. In September of
>   2007, Microsoft and Novell announced a
>   technical collaboration that includes
>   access to Microsoft's test suites for
>   Silverlight and the distribution of a
>   Media Pack for Linux users that will
>   contain licensed media codecs for
>   video and audio.
>
> Moonlight 2 was released December 17,
>   2009

http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight

**EDIT :**

For developer :

> MonoDevelop is an IDE primarily
>   designed for C# and other .NET
>   languages. MonoDevelop enables
>   developers to quickly write desktop
>   and ASP.NET Web applications on Linux,
>   Windows and Mac OSX. MonoDevelop makes
>   it easy for developers to port .NET
>   applications created with Visual
>   Studio to Linux and to maintain a
>   single code base for all platforms.
>   http://monodevelop.com/

&

[Debugging Silverlight/Moonlight Apps on Linux](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSUZRZWzTQM)

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative implementation called [Moonlight](http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight) that (unlike Silverlight) runs on Linux. It is not always up-to-date though. Every major Silverlight edition is followed by it's Moonlight counterpart sooner or later, much like .NET and Mono.

Currently Moonlight is compatible with Silverlight 2. That means your Silverlight 2 application will run on Moonlight without problems, and you don't have to do anything specific to achive that.

Silverlight 3 support will arrive soon. Here is the [roadmap](http://www.mono-project.com/MoonlightRoadmap).

**Update**: [Moonlight was discontinued](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/moonlight/) (but so was Silverlight).

Comment: The user still must install Moonlight in their browser.  Even if you can get them to do that they will often uninstall it soon afterwards because it often causes browser crashes, lock-ups, and unrequested network access.

Comment: Installing the plugin is another issue, but that's the same trouble for Windows as well.

Answer (score 4):

Well, as others have already mentioned, there's Moonlight. However, more interestingly, Microsoft has Silverlight running on Moblin, a Linux distribution developed by Intel for netbooks. This doesn't seem to be based on Moonlight. Why Microsoft didn't go for Moonlight here and put some muscle behind Moonlight's development, I have no idea.

A video of Silverlight on Moblin can be seen [here](http://news.zdnet.com/2422-19178_22-345905.html).

Then there's Silverlight for mobile devices, which isn't here yet, but that is expected to run on Symbian, which isn't Linux, but it is a non-Windows/Mac OS.